Преобразовать xml в XAMPP MySQL с помощью python
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать xml файл с помощью python, чтобы его можно было загрузить в базу данных mysql XAMPP.
Вот файл https://dropmefiles.com/tZy0r
